# Apply template to list box on button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

I want to apply "detail" template to list box after "btnDetails" button click.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>            
        <DataTemplate x:Key="detail">
            <TextBlock Text="ABC" Background="Yellow"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="MyItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource detail}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>    
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="lbDetails" ItemContainerStyle="{Binding MyItemStyle}"></ListBox>
        <Button Name="btnDetails">Details</Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

I have tried with above code but its not working.

Comment: I think the correct way to do this involves databinding to a collection in the VM. Each collection item should have some flag to determine if the item is in details mode. Also, for the ItemTemplate try to use a data template with a DataTrigger on that flag.

From what i remember, once the list items are displayed changes to item templates apply only if you refresh the collectionView that is bound to the list (so that the list replaces the items with new ones that use your new templates).

hope this helps.

Comment: @flo_badea: I don't have any collection which I can bind to List box. Simple requirement is when button is pressed or clicked; data template should be applied to List Box.

Comment: are you ok with some code? or you look forward in pure xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a sample which will modify the item template when you press the button

**Using Button (Push to on switch)**

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="detail">
            <TextBlock Text="ABC"
                       Background="Yellow" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox Name="lbDetails">
                   dummy item
                </ListBox>
                <Button Name="btnDetails">Details</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"
                         Value="True"
                         SourceName="btnDetails">
                    <Setter TargetName="lbDetails"
                            Property="ItemTemplate"
                            Value="{StaticResource detail}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

I did wrap your original controls in a content control's control template for achieving control over the IsPressed property

if you want a toggle kind of button then here is the xaml

**Using Toggle (on off switch)**

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="detail">
            <TextBlock Text="ABC"
                       Background="Yellow" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox Name="lbDetails">
                   dummy item
                </ListBox>
                <ToggleButton Name="btnDetails">Details</ToggleButton>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked"
                         Value="True"
                         SourceName="btnDetails">
                    <Setter TargetName="lbDetails"
                            Property="ItemTemplate"
                            Value="{StaticResource detail}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

in above xaml I have used toggle button in place of a regular button to keep the details on

Comment: Thanks for reply. One query, why to use Content Control and why not DataTemplate

Comment: this is due to scope limitation and property availability. Button will not be accessible inside the data template as it is not defined in it's scope. I wrapped all of them in a single container to keep it accessible in triggers. secondly only control template and data template can have property triggers so need to wrap those triggers inside a control template. thirdly Content Control is just a matter of choice you can choose any container.

Answer (score 1):

**Xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="detail">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" Background="{Binding bg}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ListBox Name="lbDetails" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource detail}"/>               
    <Button Name="btnDetails" Height="35" Content="Add" Click="btnDetails_Click_1"/>           
</StackPanel>
```

**c#**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<listboxData> lst = new ObservableCollection<listboxData>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbDetails.ItemsSource = lst;
    }

    private void btnDetails_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lst.Add(new listboxData("Textblock" + lst.Count, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.YellowGreen)));

    }

}

public class listboxData
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush bg { get; set; }

    public listboxData(string text, SolidColorBrush bg)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.bg = bg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am looking into pure XAML